# View statistics per client id in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, web-analytics

I want to view the list of distinct client ids which accessed the API and the details for each client id (clicks per page, pages visited, etc.).

Is it possible to view the statistics for each client id in google analytics, from the web interface, or from Reporting API?

Thanks.

Comment: put the client id into a custom dimension and you will be able to see it.

Comment: Depending on legislature you may have to include a warning to the users of the website that you are building individual user profiles and provide an opportunity to opt out (certainly true in Europe). Plus Google takes a dim view on attempts to track individuals (even if you use their own User ID feature you have to provide a warning to users per TOS) so this might violate at least the spirit if their TOS (or even the words if they conclude that profiles are enough to identify individuals).

Comment: @EikePierstorff I know that Google does not agree with the idea of tracking individual users, but I am using Google Analytics for some kind of kiosk machines, and I want to track the user activity on each kiosk without requiring the users to log in. So there is no personal information implied, the client id would be the kiosk UUID.

Comment: @DaImTo I am pretty new to Google Analytics, I have read a bit about how to setup a new dimension, and first it is necessary to create a property. I have to know each possible value for the custom dimension and configure it from the web interface?

Comment: @EikePierstorff client_id is a random created GUI.  Not sure how you could track that back to a person.   And I believe that it states that "User id" cant be tracked back by them it doesn't say anything about you putting your own user id from your system in.  Google doesn't have a way of tracking that back.

Comment: I haven't tried it but you should be able to get the tracker id and just put it into the dimension https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains#getClientId   I should test it it might almost be useful.

Comment: @DalmTo, yes I know how it works. Nonetheless that are laws that cover building user profiles (presumably one could identify users via statistical analyses). If you enable UserID in analytics you are reminded that you need to warn your users (additional to the requirement that they may not be used to identify users). I'm not sure how this would apply to kiosk machines, though.

Comment: @DaImTo Tank you for your suggestion, I tried it and it's working. Can you please add this solution as an answer so I could accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take your [client id](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains#getClientId) for example like this

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
});
```

and save it as a [custom dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets)

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'dimension15':  'My Custom Dimension'
});
```

You will be able to check the different client id's.   There is no way to link a client id back directly to a user as its a random guid created for them.  So as far as I know there is nothing against doing this in the [rules](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/policy).

I have done this with application tracking,  I haven't tried it with web tracking but in theory it should be the same.